# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros y obtener la respuesta de una api rest?

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero pasar estos parámetros a una api rest con el método `POST` y que este me mande un estado de si encontró al usuario y la contraseña en su base de datos pero no se como mandar los datos.

```
if(method.equals("POST")){

 http.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/x-wwww-form-urlencode");
               http.setDoInput(true);
               Uri.Builder params=new Uri.Builder()
                       .appendQueryParameter("usuario",usuario)
                       .appendQueryParameter("clave",contrasena);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar tu petición es importante que no la realices en el hilo principal por lo tanto te sugiero usar un Asynctask:

```
   public class makePOST extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public makePOST() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlString = params[0]; // Url POST
            String data = params[1]; //Datos enviados POST
            String response = "";
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                out.close();
                urlConnection.connect();

                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response+=line;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Realizarías de esta forma la petición:

```
  new makePOST().execute("https://url_post", "Datos enviados!");
```